# Combining search and sum statement

Tags: php, mysql

im new in php and sql im trying to select a username and count his total *column name* and display it. im kinda confuse how to do it. please help me out guys. thank you very much.

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['query']) ){

$query = $_POST['query'];

$raw_results = mysql_query(
    "SELECT * 
     FROM inventory 
     WHERE 
       (`serialproductkey` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR 
       (`employeename` LIKE '%".$query."%')"
) or die(mysql_error());

if( mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0 ){

// and this code that i need to combine with the search part
$tae = "SELECT SUM(total) AS TotalItemsOrdered FROM inventory";
```

Comment: Please avoid using mysql_* extension cause they are deprecated and instead, use mysqli or PDO extensions. In my opinion. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Answer (score 1):

1. `mysql_*` function are deprecated. Use `mysqli_*` or `pdo`, [read more](http://php.net/manual/it/migration55.deprecated.php)
2. `'%".$query."%'` is dangerous ... risk [SQL_injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)
3. Performance Tips: seeks to limit the number of request to the database

A possible solution to your problem is

```
$raw_results = mysql_query(
    "SELECT employeename, SUM(total) AS TotalItemsOrdered
    FROM inventory
    WHERE 
        (serialproductkey LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($query)."%') OR 
        (employeename LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($query)."%')
    GROUP BY employeename"
) or die(mysql_error());
```

[online demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87ccfa/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(total) AS TotalItemsOrdered
FROM inventory
WHERE (`serialproductkey` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR
      (`employeename` LIKE '%".$query."%')
```

Comment: @Grondag user request `select a username and count his total` you only `count his total`

Comment: Hmmm, well I'm assuming 'employeename' is the username in this case, and I do include it in the selection criteria.  I do see that you have in point in that using LIKE does not guarantee that only a single employee will be found, if any.  Depending on the need, one could use = instead of LIKE for the comparison to employee name, or handle multiple rows on the return according to whatever logic makes sense.